# Remove pictures from Twitter feed (PHP)

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've been using [TwitterOAuth](https://twitteroauth.com/) for some time, so it might be a little outdated but I think that doesn't matter in this case. The problem I have is with images. When you embed an image in Twitter post, as a result I'm getting simple text link to that page on Twitter showing the picture. That link is a part of text message from the feed.

It looks like this:

> Twitter message goes here, there some http://link.com. There is https://www.another-link.net/blabla/. Love you all. https://twitter.com/zzz/status/123123132132/photo/1

I'd like to strip those picture-links out of the text feed I'm reading by PHP. It could be as simple as strip links containing "/photo/". However, Twitter wraps all links, including those, in T.CO (link shortening tool). So all the links look like http://t.co/ZZZ0123ZZZ

> Twitter message goes here, there some http://t.co/abc. There is http://t.co/def. Love you all. http://t.co/ghi

That prevents me from simple search & replace. **I don't know which link is a real link and which is an image-link.** I can't strip the last link either because there might not be any image and the last link could be a real link to something I'd like to keep.

Is there any way to strip those image links? Other than actually follow the link with curl or something, so I know where it leads.

Comment: no, there isn't. you'd have to follow the links and see what they're pointing at.

Comment: If you look at the Tweet object you get out of the API, the un-shortened link is *partially* available and should be parseable.

Comment: @ceejayoz You're right. Thanks. $tweet->extended_entities->media(array)...-> url and expanded_url